# Voltage in a circuit across a metal wire

Tags: electric-circuits

I have a cell of e.m.f. 2.0V and negligible internal resistance, which is connected to a variable resistor R and a metal wire. The resistance of the metal wire is 3.4 Ohms. The resistance of the variable resistor may be varied between 0 and 1500 ohms. I want to know the maximum and minimum potential difference across the wire - I know that the maximum would be 2.0 Volts, but how (if possible), can I calculate the minimum voltage across the wire using this information?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the variable resistor and the wire are connected in series you can find their total equivalent resistance.  From there you can calculate the current through them and then, knowing current and resistance, you can find the voltage drop across the wire.